# Re-counting seconds / sequence within a data set

Tags: r

I have a dataset that the seconds is start from 2000, and from there I want to change it back to starting from 0 again.

I try to use this code, but it doesn't seems to work as the result show in new_seconds :

```
try3 <- try3 %>%
  mutate(new_seconds= sequence(rle(as.character(try3$Seconds))$lengths))
```

Output:

```
structure(list(Seconds = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2003), new_seconds = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: why dont you just shift by 2000: `try3 %>% mutate(new_seconds= Seconds - 2000)`

Comment: Ar, you are right. silly me